# Move animation bones hierachy

Tags: unity, animation, animator, hierarchy

I took an asset from the asset store with some animation.

The animation expect the Animator to be put directly on the object that contains all the bones.

=> fbx (with animator)
=> bones

I would like instead to have a parent object, cause having a root with 40 childs that are bones is not organized, and I will confuse my own gameobject with the character bones...So I created a parent object to the fbx, and assigned the animator and my component to it.

=> Root (components and animator)
=> fbx (without animator)
=> bones

problem is, by moving the animator up from one layer, all the animation breaks cause they can't find the bones. but I would like the animator on the root, so I can trigger script and stuff from the animation keyframes.

[image]

Is there a way to easily remap it so this ? they are just inside the child gameObject

Comment: your question does not have enough information. are you using layer masks to ignore some bone parts?

Comment: eh ? sorry, I might not know, but what is the connection of layer with what I want to achieve ?

Comment: what I have is a simple fbx, containing animation that are connected to that fbx, So that fbx need animator on it. But since I would like to put the fbx (char render) inside a root gameobject, and put my animator on that gameobject, I would like to know if I can change those animations reference to start from the parent and not the fbx directly